# How to signin without confirmed the link after registration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am using the devise:confirmable in my user model.

my requirements is that After sign up/registration , user should signed in successfully(without confirmation) and confirmation link also sent to the user's email.

in second time if user didn't confirm his account, should not be sign-in.

How to achieve this goal?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

To achieve *exactly* what you are looking for, you will need to create some magic in overriding the Devise [confirmations controller](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/confirmations_controller.rb) as well as the [sessions controller](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb). If you choose to go down this path, there are many examples of overriding Devise controllers on their [Wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/_pages) page. By enabling the `:trackable` module, you will have access to `sign_in_count` which you can use to check and allow only one until they are confirmed.

I would however, like to offer an easier solution that you may find acceptable. If you look in the `devise.rb` [initializer](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/generators/templates/devise.rb#L122) file, starting on line 122, you will see that you can allow unconfirmed access to your application for a period of time.

```
# ==> Configuration for :confirmable
# A period that the user is allowed to access the website even without
# confirming his account. For instance, if set to 2.days, the user will be
# able to access the website for two days without confirming his account,
# access will be blocked just in the third day. Default is 0.days, meaning
# the user cannot access the website without confirming his account.
# config.allow_unconfirmed_access_for = 2.days
```

I think in the end, enabling this feature, and setting it to something acceptable for your application will be the better approach, both from a developer and end user standpoint. I would also be sure to put something in the [locale](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/config/locales/en.yml) on line 34 for `send_instructions` notifying the user that they have x number of hours/days to use the sight before they must confirm their account through the email.

Comment: Any trick to getting this to work?  I uncommented the line, but it doesn't seem to be working when trying to log in via the API.

Answer (score 3):

Easiest would be that you indicate `config.allow_unconfirmed_access_for = 2.minutes` so that immediately after registering he will be signed in but after two minutes, he won't be able to sign in unless he signs out and in within two minutes.